# SQL group by as subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table and one column contain id number as number + letters. I know jow to separate and create another (new) column but i would like to group by new column:

```
 SELECT  A.COLUMN1 ,
         B.COLUMN1,  
        (LEFT(SUBSTRING(B.COLUMN1, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', B.COLUMN1), 10),
               PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(B.COLUMN1, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', B.COLUMN1), 10) + 'X') -1)) as name2

    FROM    TABLE_B AS B           
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_A AS A ON B.COLUMN123 = A.COLUMN123

    WHERE   A.COLUMN1='VALUE'
GROUP BY B.COLUMN1,  A.COLUMN1
```

SO my report looks like:

```
    name1   name2  name2
    VALUE1  1      1
    VALUE   2      2
    VALUE3  3      1
    VALUE   4      4
    VALUE   27xz   27
   VALUE    27zx    27
```

how to group by name2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a CTE or subquery:

```
 WITH cte as (
       SELECT A.COLUMN1, B.COLUMN1,  
              (LEFT(SUBSTRING(B.COLUMN1, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', B.COLUMN1), 10),
               PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(B.COLUMN1, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', B.COLUMN1), 10) + 'X') -1)) as new_column
       FROM TABLE_B B LEFT OUTER JOIN
            TABLE_A A
            ON B.COLUMN123 = A.COLUMN123
       WHERE A.COLUMN1 = 'VALUE'
      )
SELECT new_column, COUNT(*)
FROM cte
GROUP BY new_column;
```